# restore database in ssms 2017 selected bak file in device option and showing nothing in Backup sets to restore option and disable Ok button too

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

I am trying to restore sample database adventureworks in SSMS 2017
right Click in Database
selected Restore Database
in Device option then option ADD
selected AdventureWorks2017.bak file in my hard drive
c:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER_2017\MSSQL\Backup
press Ok
and nothing showing in Destination and Backup sets to retore
and disable Ok Button in this Window
(filled in Destination Database)
the same

could somebody help me
thank you

Comment: I am using SQL Sever 2017 Developer Edition

Comment: error message not backupset selected to be restored

Comment: Is the SQL instance on your local machine?

Comment: have you got a screenshot?

Comment: yes it is in my local machine

Comment: I am reinstall sql server with standard version 2016 to try restore database in this version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the file to default backup repository for SqlServer:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL[##].[instanceName]\MSSQL\Backup

or check the permissions for this folder, to find the SQL Instance username... to add that user to permissions for the folder where the .bak file resides